# Equation doesn't fit in longtable cell

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, longtable

I try to put an equation on table, but it doesn't fit right. Specifically, the fit is much too tight.

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
• & $\begin{array}{ll}
\Rightarrow a+b &> \dfrac{2013}{b}(a+b)+\dfrac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
    &= 2013 + \dfrac{2013a}{b}+\dfrac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
    &\geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\dfrac{2013a}{b}.\dfrac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
    &= \left( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \right)^2
\end{array}$ \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

I'm working on a long table, and I got amount of situations like this. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post not just code snippets but a [fully compilable minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001). That way, would-be writers of answers don't have to guess at which document class you use and which packages must be loaded in order to get your code to compile. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Most importantly, don't use an `array` environment, which uses textstyle-math settings by default. Use an `aligned` environment, as its default is displaystyle math.
- Don't use a `.` (dot) as a symbol to denote multiplication; use `\cdot` instead. Or, just omit the symbol as it's not really needed.

  Remark: If you wanted the `\textbullet` item in the first column to be aligned at the top rather than in the middle, simply use `\begin{aligned}[t]` instead of just `\begin{aligned}`.
- Insert a (typographic) strut in one of the numerator terms in the first row; this will increase the vertical distance to the preceding horizontal line.
- The parentheses generated by `\left(` and `\right)` in the final row are too large, typographically speaking. Instead, use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.
- Optional: load the `array` package and issue the directive `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` to create a table with a (slightly) more "open" look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array} % for \extrarowheight macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
\newcommand\Tstrut{\smash[b]{\strut}} % "top strut"
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbullet & 
  $\begin{aligned}
  \Rightarrow a+b &> \frac{2013\Tstrut}{b}(a+b)+\frac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
    &= 2013 + \frac{2013a}{b}+\frac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
    &\geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\frac{2013a}{b}\cdot\frac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
    &= \bigl( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \,\bigr)^2
  \end{aligned}$ \\ 
\hline 
\textbullet & \textbullet \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question about how one might automate (and improve) the spacing around horizontal lines. In my view, one is actually asking the wrong question if one wishes to improve the vertical spacing above and below horizontal lines drawn by `\hline` and `\cline`. Instead, one should ask, why are we using `\hline` and `\cline` at all? The [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package provides the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`, which automatically produce *much better* spacing. Using these macros instead of `\hline` and `\cline`, and omitting all vertical rules, immediately produces a much more pleasing and easy-to-grasp layout. This is illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}cc@{}}

\toprule 
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot

\textbullet & 
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
  \Rightarrow a+b &> \frac{2013}{b}(a+b)+\frac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
    &= 2013 + \frac{2013a}{b}+\frac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
    &\geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\frac{2013a}{b}\cdot\frac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
    &= \bigl( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \,\bigr)^2
  \end{aligned}$ \\ 
  
\midrule

\textbullet & \textbullet \\ 

\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: it actually works nicely, thank you. By the way, I have a lot of \dfrac in my table, so is there any idea to fix it, instead of adding \mathstrut to all ?

Comment: @NguyenBao - A very good question! I think it's sufficiently important that I've written an addendum to my answer. Basically, I think the optimal solution to the spacing issues raised by the output of `\dfrac` being too close to  the preceding `\hline` is to stop using `\hline` and `\cline` entirely. Instead, use the line-drawing commands of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. And, while you're at it, omit all vertical rules: they aren't needed, and they won't be missed. Really! Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for helping me so enthusiastic, but another problem is coming. Some rows I used \cdashline (by using rthe arydshln package) to seperate, now, the booktabs package draws lines automatically, so if I want to add a dash line, what should I do ?

Comment: @NguyenBao - Instead of `\cdashline` (or `\cline`...), consider using `\addlinespace` -- just a band of whitespace. It's amazingly effective.

Answer (score 5):

with `cellspace` and `amsmath` (`mathtools`) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace, longtable}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|Sc|}% <-- S activate settings for cellspace
    \hline
\textbullet &
    $\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow a+b & > \frac{2013}{b}(a+b)+\frac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
                & = 2013 + \frac{2013a}{b}+\frac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
                & \geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\frac{2013a}{b}\cdot\frac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
                & = \bigl( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \,\bigr)^2
     \end{aligned}$             \\
    \hline
\textbullet     & \textbullet   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you're loading the `cellspace` package and are setting the length variable `cellspacetoplimit`, it's no longer necessary to insert a `\mathstrut`, right?

Comment: @Mico, I overlooked it ... of course it is in my case  surplus. Deleted

Answer (score 2):

You use display fractions `dfrac` in your array, so you need to increase `\arraystretch` to accommodate them.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
• & \renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}$\begin{array}{ll}
\Rightarrow a+b &> \dfrac{2013}{b}(a+b)+\dfrac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
    &= 2013 + \dfrac{2013a}{b}+\dfrac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
    &\geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\dfrac{2013a}{b}.\dfrac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
    &= \left( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \right)^2
\end{array}$ \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** @Mico asked in comments to make a more consistent spacing around the `>`.  Switching to `aligned` does this.  And, while we at it, let's use `booktabs` too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath,amssymb, booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\toprule
• &\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}$\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow a+b &> \dfrac{2013}{b}(a+b)+\dfrac{2014}{a}(a+b) \\
    &= 2013 + \dfrac{2013a}{b}+\dfrac{2014b}{a} + 2014 \\
    &\geqslant 2013 + 2\sqrt{\dfrac{2013a}{b}.\dfrac{2014b}{a}} + 2014 \\
    &= \left( \sqrt{2013} + \sqrt{2014} \right)^2
\end{aligned}$ \\ 
\midrule
• & • \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing around the `>` symbol in the first row is quite asymmetric. Any way to improve this?

Comment: \renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5} stretched everything in the rest of table. Can I just limit its effect in a local ? And what's the difference between \hline, \cline and \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule?